# AJAX request redirecting in Tornado: it works, but I don't understand how

Tags: python, tornado

I am building a home web radio server. Basically, the device talk to my home server that redirect request to the real web radio server. I parse the returned HTML to change the binding of the play buttons to make them playing on the home server instead of the device. It works very well.

I use `tornado`, my main handler is:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, url):
        query = ''
        if self.request.query:
            query = '?' + self.request.query
        url = base_url + urllib.request.quote(url) + query # base url is the real server address
        raw_data = opener.open(url).read()
        data = filter_data(raw_data) # parse HTML with Beautiful soup
        self.write(data)

    def post(self, url): # exclusively AJAX calls
        url = base_url + urllib.request.quote(url)
        request = urllib.request.Request(url, data=self.request.body, method='POST')
        data = opener.open(request).read().decode('utf-8')
        try:
            json.loads(data)
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
        self.write(data)
```

The opener is required:

```
cj = CookieJar()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
```

I don't understand how it works: the request that I construct with `urllib.request` has no headers, so how the remote server can reply?

The problem is that it works only in the context of a Tornado request. If I try to do the same thing outside it, it does not work:

```
def get_song(radioUID):
    url = base_url + 'fr/OnAir/GetCurrentSong' # same url that works in tornado
    data = bytes(json.dumps({ 'radioUID': radioUID}), encoding='utf-8')
    request = urllib.request.Request(url, data=data, method='POST')
    response = opener.open(request).read().decode('utf-8')
    print(response)
```

Answers always `'false'` instead of the expected json object. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You might consider to use `AsyncHTTPClient` instead anyway, because Tornado is asynchronous and using blocking functions stops IOLoop from processing other requests. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44772230/1643900).

Comment: Of course you are right. But I am very new to tornado and more generally to HTTP internals. This is a school case and for now, I just would like to understand how this works.